# Which font is the basis for "1942 report" by Johan Holmdahl?

Tags: font-identification, font-recommendation, typesetting

The TrueType Font »1942 report« by Johan Holmdahl is an equidistant typeface. It resembles the »Makina rough« font by representing the individual letters in an eroded form. Particularly noteworthy are the numbers 3, 5, 7 and 9 with descenders and 4, 6 and 8 with ascenders.

[image: Sample by Font Squirrel https://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/1942-report]

I am looking for the character set which forms the basis for this font, that is the "non-eroded" form?

I tried the site [What Font Is](https://www.whatfontis.com). There, however, reference is only made to eroded variants.

Answer (score 9):

Make and advanced search at myfonts.com looking for *[typewriter](https://www.myfonts.com/search/typewriter)*

[Passport Regular](https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/coniglio/passport/)

[image: Passport Regular]

[Tired of Courier Bold](https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/ingrimayne/tiredofcourier/)

[image: Tired of Courier]

[EF Techno Script](https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/ef/techno-script-ef/)

[image: Techno Script]

[Coronette](https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/chank/coronette/)

[image: Coronette]

Comment: The Passport Font is a hit - but this font is also "eroded". So it can not be the basic form. Makina from Besnard (https://www.fonts.com/font/besnard/makina) is almost perfect, but the number 4 is not fitting. I wonder why?

Comment: I'm sure if you make an extensive search you'll find it. Try Google with "clean typewriter font". I update the answer with a new specimen.